# Pyautogui typewrite is writing only numbers

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am trying to automate some GUI actions using the Python library pyautogui.

Doing the simple command of:

```
pyautogui.typewrite("a1b2c3")
```

Is resulting in `123` being written.

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't need say *thanks* here :), please check [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Are the  missing chars *actually* `a`, `b`, & `c`, or some non-ascii characters?

Comment: Did you try `pyautogui.typewrite(u"a1b2c3")`? Which Python version?

Comment: Working well...What's your os and python version?

Answer (score 0):

Try just pyautogui.write(), although it's not utility, if you need to combine the functionality you'll need to be very explicit.

edit: 8/8
typewrite() is a test function, try write() instead