# Missing symbols in Pyautogui typewriter

Tags: python, pyautogui

I have a problem, that consists in following: Pyautogui typewrite won't type letters, only numbers. For example, when I execute

```
pyautogui.typewrite("abc123")
```

only "123" appears.
This question is similar to this one:
[Pyautogui typewrite is writing only numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33844149/5320650)
Unfortunately, there are no answers about the issue, as well as other Internet topics. 
I have the Windows 7 machine and Python 3.5.

Comment: Python 3.5 here (but Win 10, if that's relevant). I don't have this problem and I'm using pyautogui 0.9.33. Is yours perhaps an earlier version with a bug? although it doesn't seem to appear on their [issues](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in the typewrite function of PyAutoGui. I workaround it with this function which preprocesses the string into keypresses instead. Note that this version of the function leaves a comma at the end of the output array so that you can easily append more characters or button presses at the end.

```
def preprocess(something):
    something = str(something)
    output = []
    for x in range(len(something)):
        output.append(something[x])
        output.append(',')
    return output
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. I was not able to send letters using typewrite() function.This bug in PyAutoGUI can be overcome by installing OpenCV 3.1.0

Download openCV 3.1.0 from below site:

1) https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/3.1.0/opencv-
 3.1.0.exe/download

2) Extract the OpenCV -> Then go to OpenCV\build\python\2.7\x64 and copy cv2.pyd to C:\Python27\Lib\Site-packages

And your problem will be solved. Give it a try, it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem couple of days ago

Try using other pyautogui functions that presses keyboard keys like pyautogui.press("k")

If you have a problem with  all keyboard functions related to letters in general it's probably because your default input language is set to something other than english

you can fix that easily by going to your **keyboard and input settings** and changing the **default input language** to english

you'll still be able to write in your first language and it will hopefully solve your problem